# Set button text to question mark

Tags: android, button

I need to set a button's text to just `?`.
I'm happy to do it via Java, but would rather do it via the XML.
Is it possible?

I've tried `android:text="?"`  and `android:text="&#63;"` but it did not work.
Then I set one of the string resources to `?`, and when that did not work I set it to `&#63;`referenced that but it doesn't work!

How do I set the button caption to <kbd>?</kbd> using XML?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to escape the question mark...

```
android:text="\?"
```

Comment: I thought I was being stupid... I think the fact it doesn't show it in the IDE must have confused me a bit... Thanks so much!

Comment: Weird cause when I put \? in the xml, it shows as \? in the Graphical Layout. Ahh but when I put \? in the string resource it shows as just ? in the Graphical Layout. Now for device testing...

Answer (score 2):

Write "\?" Intead normal or ASCII form.

Answer (score 0):

You try this way.. just give space before or after ? this will work i think..

android:text=" ?" or android:text="? "

Answer (score 0):

give the space before writing the ?(android:text=" ?")...it's working fine.other wise. you have to add image to button(android:background="@drawable/image"). or u need to take imagebutton add question mark image to it.

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem is that in some versions of the Eclipse Android Layout Editor, it will freak out with a question mark as its text on a button.  I submitted a bug report, and after a year I received a note saying that the bug is fixed.

So make sure you have version 21.1 or greater of the API to get the bug fix.

See my question about this: [Android Layout Editor Freaks Out on Question Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367469/android-layout-editor-freaks-out-on-question-mark)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a \ before the question mark like this "\?".